# Explicitly causing AccessViolationException in a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net

I'm debugging a pesky `AccessViolationException` in a rather large .NET application (one that takes down the entire process, leaving nothing but an Event Viewer entry). There's a *lot* of distracting things going on in that application, making root cause analysis quite hard. I would like to have a "toy problem" version, but being (at best) rusty at C++, I'm having a hard time creating a .NET application that dies with such an exception.

I've searched and found for example [this somewhat old post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chappell/2005/01/12/why-does-software-crash-1-the-access-violation/) that shows code that should throw the exception I want. But if I compile this:

```
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff");

    try
    {
        int foo = (*((int*)0));
    }
    catch (AccessViolationException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Don't want to reach this.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Or this:

```
static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff");

    try
    {

        int foo;
        int* ip = null;
        foo = *ip; //crash!
    }
    catch (AccessViolationException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Don't want to reach this.");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

PS. The `catch` block is there because my *actual* scenario I'm trying to represent is one where I cannot catch the exception either (so I cannot just `throw` it myself).

with the "Allow unsafe code" option on, in a fresh .NET Console application, it crashes with a *Null Reference Exception*, not an `AccessViolationException`. Although I'm not all too surprised, and kind of understand why that is the case, I'm still left with the original problem.

**Bottom line:**: is there an easy way to create a .NET application that causes an `AccessViolationException` on demand, preferably in a way that the process completely dies without the option of exception handling, leaving only a trace in the Event Viewer?

Comment: can't you just `throw new AccessViolationException();` if the only thing you want is to launch the exception?

Comment: Replace `0` (or `null`) with `-1`.

Comment: @JorgeY. Good point, I've added an explanation to the question why that won't be enough.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Tyvm, that did the trick! (If you would, please add it as an answer, and if you can add a note on *why* that works, that would be great!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `0` (or `null`) with `-1` — it should trigger the desired behavior because *−1*, when implicitly casted to a pointer, results in *0xFFFFFFFF…* which usually belongs to kernel-mode address space (both in Windows and *nix) that you are not allowed to read from user-mode programs.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you don't want to use "unsafe" in C#, you can create simple C++ CLR project in your solution and do everything you want with memory and other resources.  ))

```
using namespace System;
namespace ClassLibrary1 {

public ref class Class1
{
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
public:
    void ThrowException()
    {
        int * p = (int*)-1;
        *p = 10;
    }
};
```

}

This method give us AccessViolationException.

Answer (score 0):

Colleague came up with a version that doesn't even need `unsafe` code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using static System.Console;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine("Doing stuff");

        try
        {
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(1, new IntPtr(1), true);
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException)
        {
            WriteLine("Should not reach this.");
        }
        finally
        {
            WriteLine("Should not reach even this.");
        }

        WriteLine("Waiting");
        ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The `try` block's statement will kill the whole thing, no other code is executed, not even the `finally` block.